# Rewrite Rule to map to URL Parameter without extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to use HTACCESS to rewrite the following url:

```
http://example.com/index.php?item_id=123456
```

I would like it rewritten as:

```
http://example.com/213456
```

The parameter item_id is to be captured in my php file with the following code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['item_id'])) {
        $url_item = $_GET['item_id'];
        $urlParmResult = filter_var($url_item, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        echo $urlParmResult;
    }else{
        echo "The link you requested does not exist.";
    }
?>
```

I am using the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?item_id=$1 [L]
```

however all i get returned on the page is:

```
index.php
```

Can someone please help me out? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?item_id=$1 [L]
```

Which eliminates existing files or directories, to avoid redirect index to index

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you! Would you mind describing a bit of whats going on here with the RewriteCond?

Comment: You can read all about files or directories tests here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a huge help!

Comment: Had to wait 11 minutes before accepting the answer so I went to lunch. First thing I did upon coming back!